# ¿Por qué una búsqueda en un dataframe de pandas me devuelve indices fuera de rango?

Tags: pandas

Estoy usando un jupyter notebook configurado con python3 y cargo las siguientes librerías:

```
# Cargamos librerias
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy  as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import altair as alt
import seaborn as sns
from  sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
```

Tengo un dataframe donde he eliminado algunas columnas que no cumplen un determinado requesito con el método drop(inplace=True). Parece ser que en realidad no las borra sino que "las marca" como no existentes y no actualiza los indices. Asi que para evitar problemas obtengo una lista de los indices de fila válidos con:

```
len(data) -> 28070
rowok = data.index.tolist()
len(rowok) -> 28070
```

Mas adelante, quiero hacer una transformación de BoxCox a determinadas columnas de esas filas. Por ello había pensado en algo como (icont es
una lista con los números de columna que quiero transformar):

```
for i in icont:
    x,l_val = sc.stats.boxcox(data.iloc[rowok,i]+1)
    x = x.tolist()
```

y me dice que:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-80-7d859986010c> in <module>()
      7 # los desplazamos en una unidad previamente
      8 for i in icont:
----> 9     x,l_val = sc.stats.boxcox(data.iloc[rowok,i]+1)
     10     #x,l_val = sc.stats.boxcox(data.iloc[:,i].isin(rowok)+1)
     11     x = x.tolist()

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in 
__getitem__(self, key)
   1365             except (KeyError, IndexError):
   1366                 pass
-> 1367             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1368         else:
   1369             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in 
_getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   1735     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
   1736 
-> 1737         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
   1738         try:
   1739             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in 
_has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    202             if i >= self.obj.ndim:
    203                 raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
--> 204             if not self._has_valid_type(k, i):
    205                 raise ValueError("Location based indexing can 
only have "
    206                                  "[{types}] types"

 /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in 
 _has_valid_type(self, key, axis)
   1672             return self._is_valid_integer(key, axis)
   1673         elif is_list_like_indexer(key):
-> 1674             return self._is_valid_list_like(key, axis)
   1675         return False
   1676 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in 
_is_valid_list_like(self, key, axis)
   1729         if (hasattr(arr, '__len__') and len(arr) and
   1730                 (arr.max() >= l or arr.min() < -l)):
-> 1731             raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-
bounds")
   1732 
   1733         return True

 IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

Lo cual sugiere que rowok tiene más valores de los que debiera? ¿Cómo puede ser? ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El índice de una tabla pandas puede contener cualquier secuencia de valores, no necesariamente enteros ni correlativos. Eso puede resultar bastante confuso y proclive a errores cuando los índices son en realidad enteros, pues en ese caso cuando decimos `df[0]` ¿a qué me quiero referir? ¿A la fila que tiene como índice un cero, o a la primera fila del dataframe (que podría tener cualquier valor como índice)?

Para deshacer esa ambigüedad `pandas` introdujo dos formas de referirse a una fila.

- La primera es `df.loc[n]` en la cual `n` se interpreta como un valor de índice (y si ese valor no aparece entre los índices, se tendrá un error de índice no encontrado, o `KeyError`)
- La segunda es `df.iloc[n]` en la cual `n` se interpreta simplemente como el número de orden de la fila (siendo `0` la primera). En este caso el error se produce cuando `n` es mayor que el número de filas, y el error producido es `IndexError`.

Un ejemplo puede ayudar a entenderlo. Supón que tienes el siguiente dataframe:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['uno', 'tres', 'cinco', 'ocho'], index=[1,3,5,8])
```

[image: df]

En ese caso:

- `df.loc[3]` te dará el elemento "tres"
- `df.iloc[3]` te dará el elemento "ocho" (que es el que está en la fila 3, ya que se numeran desde 0 como dijimos)
- `df.loc[2]` te dará un `KeyError`
- `df.iloc[2]` te dará el elemento "cinco"
- `df.loc[8]` te dará el elemento "ocho"
- `df.iloc[8]` te dará un `IndexError`

Una vez sabido todo esto, podemos diagnosticar tu problema. Tras haber eliminado algunas filas, con las que han quedado podrias usar `loc` para acceder a ellas, pero tu código ha usado `iloc`, lo que produce el mismo efecto que tratr de acceder a `df.iloc[8]` en el caso anterior.